# Display filter option in Search result page in Opencart

Tags: php, search, filter, opencart, categories

I am using **Opencart** `Version 2.0.3.1.`

I want to display the `filter` in `Search result page`. But `filter option` is not displaying in `search result page`.

But in `category page` I can display the `filter`.

How can I do this? please help me...

Answer (score 2):

You can not display filter module in search page.As filter requires category data and using that category data it functions. And in search page there might be products from different categories. So no option to display filters on search page. But if you still want to do so than build your own code.

> **Edit**

Check in module/filter.php controller :-

```
    if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
    } else {
        $parts = array();
    }


    $category_id = end($parts);

    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

    if ($category_info) {

   ........

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/filter.tpl')) {
        return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/filter.tpl', $data);
    } else {
        return $this->load->view('default/template/module/filter.tpl', $data);
    }

    }
```